# Visual Studio Code Destroyed all my files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using visual studio code for about a year now.  Recently I went to save one of my files and visual studio code gave me the error message this file conflict with a previous version. I clicked on the error and it presented me with a screen show the differences. I turned out I had added a line at the top importing defining a new constant. When I clicked override visual studio code presented me with a blank file. I went to look at my files and found that every file I have every worked on in the program has been changed to a blank file. Now whenever I try to save a file nothing happens, and I can't close tabs. I use a macbook if that helps in any way. Does anyone know how I could retrieve my files and how to prevent this prom happening again.

Edit: this applies to all my files not just ones associated with this project.

Comment: **FIRST of ALL:** If the project was important to you, you should have added it to a repository. There is no excuse, considering GitHub offers free public repositories!!!. **SECONDLY:** Have you checked to see if there is anything located in your local history's directory? You might be surprised what was kept.  **AND LASTLY:**  Did you look in your trash to see if the projects files were caught by it?

Comment: @j D3V I did have a github reporsity but this since I didn't have a change to update my latest changes my most recent work is all gone. Aditionally many of the programs were simple toy examples that though annoying to lose were never important enough to back up, or ones I had made before I used github. However since visual studio can no longer save files I can't redo all work I was doing I tried looking in the trash but they weren't deleted just modified to be blank. This applies not just to this project on but every file I have every worked I appologize if that was not clear.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear this happened to you. FWIW, everyone who is getting started with development loses a chunk of work at some point and learns the importance of very strict version control practices.  Remember- commits don't cost anything, so you might as well make them frequently! I have never had any such experience with VSCode, but looking around on the web it seems like some others have lost work. I would recommend seeing if any of them have a similar issue to you; if not, perhaps you should open a ticket w/ VSCode to detail the issue and see if they have a fix. Good luck, happy coding!

Comment: Its a strange thing to happen. No one else has reported any similar issues.

Comment: Make sure you always commit to a repository. Even snippets & configuration files you want. **Check this out** https://github.com/JAYD3V/Snips-Clips-n-Configs That link shows the repository I use, and how I organize it. Its kind of a mess, but i know where everything is. Its like my abstract sloppy desk in a way. I publicized so I can share snippets with people when I need to, but you can keep it private if you want.

Comment: Also, VS Code recently released Local history. If you configure local history, and the settings sync feature, you shouldn't ever loose work, at-least not without being able to blame yourself. I did loose somthing recently, and it was my own fault because I cleared my locally history, and shouldn't have.